# Solve system of linear equations in Spark

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

I have a system of linear equations in the form of `Ax = b` to solve in Spark.

`A` is `n by n`

`b` is `n by 1`

I represent`A` in the form of `IndexedRowMatrix` or `RowMatrix` and `b` in the form of `DenseMatrix` or `DenseVector`.

How can I solve this system to calculate the `x` vector?

If the suggested solution is [Cholesky Decomposition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/CholeskyDecomposition.scala), would you please guide me through doing it as it is not part of the public API ? For example if the original matrix `A` is:

```
1,2,3,4
2,1,5,6
3,5,1,7
4,6,7,1
```

and `b` is:

```
5,6,7,8
```

What is passed as argument to the `solve` method ?

Any other solution other than inversing `A` would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have to use Spark? That matrix is very small.

Comment: And what do you mean "not part of the public API"? "mllib.linalg" most definitely is part of the public MLlib package

Comment: Actually this is just a sample I mentioned to get an idea for my huge dataset.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is a private object which is not accessible as part of the public API.

Comment: Cholesky Decomposition is used by [WeightedLeastSquares](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala). You won't get exact solution (unless you set regParam to 0). You need to create an RDD of Instance(features: Vector, label: Double, weight: Double). and pass it to WeightedLeastSquares.fit

Comment: Ah this class is also private (hate spark api). Need then to use [LinearRegression](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L191). If you'll have #features (columns in matrix A) > 4096 - otherwise it would use LBFGS solver. But in any case your problem is linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the question is still relevant to you or not, but another solution to the question is to invert the coefficient matrix and then multiply the inverted matrix to the vector b. There are many matrix inversion algorithm. One such algorithm can be found in the following paper

[SPIN: A Fast and Scalable Matrix Inversion Method in Apache Spark](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04723.pdf)

You can find the complete code on [GitHub link](https://github.com/chandan-misra/Spark-Matrix-Inverse/blob/master/StrassenInverse.java) also.

Cheers!!